# Error in using buttons to input numbers!

Tags: serial

This is a mini project of mine, which is to be implemented in another.
Here, I'm trying to make arduino output numbers in the serial window based on the diff. buttons pressed(there are four of them in my case).
What I want:

- the initial array is 0000.
- if I press button one, then button three, the array should be 1010
- if I press button one two times, and button 4 three  times, the
  resultant array should be 2003......and so on.you might have got what
  I'm trying to do here.   the problem is , all I'm getting is 0000,
  ALL THE TIME.

My code is below, and I'm a newbie, so any corrections(+advice?) given would be greatly appreciated.
(Also I don't know where to print the output :P I did it in `loop()` so it keeps on printing it :P)

```
CODE:

//the buttons:

const int b1=8;
const int b2=9;
const int b3=10;
const int b4=11;
//variables to store previous button press and currend button press , used to eliminate switch bouncing
boolean pb1=LOW;
boolean cb1=LOW;

boolean pb2=LOW;
boolean cb2=LOW;

boolean pb3=LOW;
boolean cb3=LOW;

boolean pb4=LOW;
boolean cb4=LOW;


//variables to store numbers:

int w=0;  
int x=0;  
int y=0;  
int z=0;  

int var_array [4]={w,x,y,z};  

void setup() {  
  // put your setup code here, to run once:  
  pinMode(b1,INPUT);  
  pinMode(b2,INPUT);  
  pinMode(b3,INPUT);  
  pinMode(b4,INPUT);  

 Serial.begin(9600);   


}  

boolean debounce1(boolean last)  
{  
   boolean current=digitalRead(b1);  
  if(last != current)  
  {  
      delay(5);  
    }  
      current=digitalRead(b1);  
      return current;    
  }  

boolean debounce2(boolean last)  
{  
   boolean current=digitalRead(b2);  
  if(last != current)  
  {  
      delay(5);  
    }  
      current=digitalRead(b2);  
      return current;    
  }  

  boolean debounce3(boolean last)  
{  
   boolean current=digitalRead(b3);  
  if(last != current)  
  {  
      delay(5);  
    }  
      current=digitalRead(b3);  
      return current;     
  }  

  boolean debounce4(boolean last)  
{  
   boolean current=digitalRead(b4);  
  if(last != current)  
  {  
      delay(5);  
    }  
      current=digitalRead(b4);  
      return current;    
  }  


void loop() {  
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:  
  cb1=debounce1(pb1);  
  cb2=debounce2(pb2);   
  cb3=debounce3(pb3);  
  cb4=debounce4(pb4);  

     if (pb1==LOW&&cb1==HIGH)     
   {  
      w++;  
    }  
    pb1=cb1;  


    if (pb2==LOW&&cb2==HIGH)     
   {  
      x++;  
    }  
    pb2=cb2;  


    if (pb3==LOW&&cb3==HIGH)     
   {  
      y++;  
    }  
    pb3=cb3;  

    if (pb4==LOW&&cb4==HIGH)      
   {  
      z++;  
    }  
    pb4=cb4;  

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)  
Serial.print(var_array[i]);  

Serial.println();  

delay(500);

}
```

Comment: At first glance it looks like your problem is you have a fraction of a millisecond where the buttons are being read. The rest of the time you are stuck in a delay.

Answer (score 1):

In your C program all the variables including the array occupy their own space in memory.  In the line "int var_array [4]={w,x,y,z};" all you did was create 4 more variables (elements of the array var_array) in memory and initialized them to the values found in variables (w, x, y & z) in a different part of memory.  So when you incremented the variables in memory pointed to by the names w, x, y and z... you did nothing to the variables in memory pointed to by the elements of the var_array.

For example, in this program:

```
main()
{
 int w=0;
 int x=1;
 int y=2;
 int z=3;

 int var_array [4]={w,x,y,z};

 printf("w %d x %d y %d z %d\n",w,x,y,z);
 printf("var_array %d %d %d %d\n", var_array[0],var_array[1],var_array[2],var_array[3]);

 w += 1;
 x += 2;
 y += 4;
 z += 5;

 printf("w %d x %d y %d z %d\n",w,x,y,z);
 printf("var_array %d %d %d %d\n", var_array[0],var_array[1],var_array[2],var_array[3]);
}
```

The output is this:

```
w 0 x 1 y 2 z 3
var_array 0 1 2 3
w 1 x 3 y 6 z 8
var_array 0 1 2 3
```

Notice how the array values do not change.

If you really want to do this, you need to make the array var_array an array of pointers and point each element to each variable (w, x, y & z).

For example:

```
main()
{
 int w=0;
 int x=1;
 int y=2;
 int z=3;

 int * var_array [4]={&w,&x,&y,&z};

 printf("w %d x %d y %d z %d\n",w,x,y,z);
 printf("var_array %d %d %d %d\n", *var_array[0],*var_array[1],*var_array[2],*var_array[3]);

 w += 1;
 x += 2;
 y += 4;
 z += 5;

 printf("w %d x %d y %d z %d\n",w,x,y,z);
 printf("var_array %d %d %d %d\n", *var_array[0],*var_array[1],*var_array[2],*var_array[3]);
}
```

Now produces this output:

```
w 0 x 1 y 2 z 3
var_array 0 1 2 3
w 1 x 3 y 6 z 8
var_array 1 3 6 8
```